# Capture a frame of video

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to capture a frame of a video, but I am always getting this exception:

> (index):57 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'toBlob' on
>   'HTMLCanvasElement': 1 argument required, but only 0 present.
>       at getFrame ((index):57)
>       at HTMLSpanElement.onclick ((index):70)

Here is the html code:

```
<content>
            <div class="out">
                <div class="video-box">
                    <span class="button create-frame" onclick=getFrame()>Get Frame</span>
                    <video id="test" class="video" width="480" height="360" controls="true">
                    <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    </video>

            <div class="frame-box ">
                <canvas id="canvas" class="canvas hidden" width="480" height="360"></canvas>
                <ul class="frames">
                </ul>
            </div>
</content>
```

and here is the javascript code for capturing the frame

```
function getFrame() {

     var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
     var video = document.getElementById('test');

    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video,0,0,480,360);
     var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

         var img = document.createElement('img');
         canvas.toBlob() = (blob) => {
      img.src = window.URL.createObjectUrl(blob);
    };
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong.

```
canvas.toBlob() = (blob) => {
    img.src = window.URL.createObjectUrl(blob);
};
```

What you're actually doing there is trying to assign a function reference to the returned value of `toBlob()` (which is error'ing).

Instead you need to *pass* the function reference as the first argument of `toBlob()`:

```
canvas.toBlob(blob => {
    img.src = window.URL.createObjectUrl(blob);
});
```

Comment: thank you for the fast answer but now im getting this error

(index):58 Uncaught TypeError: window.URL.createObjectUrl is not a function
    at (index):58

Comment: createObjectU**RL** and it was erroring before the assignmrnt to undefined, toBlob requires at least one argument.

Comment: ...which makes my answer valid. This new issue, as @Kaiido points out, is a typo on your part.